# "El Male Rachamim" on Tisha b'Av

Tags: tachanun, tisha-bav, memory

Typically we do not say "El Male" on days when tachnun would not be said, however, is this true of Tisha b'Av, when we have our national day of aveilut?

Answer (score 3):

[*Shaare Efrayim* 10:27](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34320&pgnum=309) indicates it's not said on 9 *Av*.